# What does MultiFactor mean in Firebase Auth

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I was reading the Firebase Auth docs and in the "Manage Users" section I found this:

> ```
> var multiFactorString = "MultiFactor: "
>  for info in user.multiFactor.enrolledFactors {
>    multiFactorString += info.displayName ?? "[DispayName]"
>    multiFactorString += " "
>  }
>  // ...
> ```

I wanted to know what this `multifactorString` means, or generally, what MultiFactor means in context to FirebaseAuth. Is it used to check what all providers a user can log in with (such as Google or Apple)? Or is it used for something completely different?

Please let me know what MultiFactor means, how I can make use of a `MulitFactor` object, and if my assumption was correct.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

GCIP (Google Cloud Identity Platform) is the upgraded version of Firebase Auth for Google Cloud developers. It also supports multi-factor authentication using SMS as a second factor. Basically after you sign in with email/password, or a social provider like Google or Facebook, you can still require an additional SMS challenge (this is independent on whether the user is using 2FA with Google)

The documentation for using this in iOS is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/ios/mfa).

The documentation you are referring to is the Admin SDK for managing enrolled second factors on a user. With this feature, you are able to enroll multiple second factors on the same user and you can assign them user friendly names for the user to choose from after completing the first challenge. This is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/manage-mfa-users#creating_a_user).

Comment: Is there a sample project that implement it? We want to use email/password and social provider of Firebase Auth but at the same time its SMS OTP. Thanks