# How to offer email/password login with 2FA in Google Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am using the Firebase authentication service to offer various logins for my users. I also configured the standard "email/password" login and would like to add 2FA support to the login procedure.

I know Firebase offers a password-less login as well, but I prefer the default *email+password+2FA* approach where 2FA uses either Email or text message.

Am I missing something or is this option not available?

Comment: Multi-factor authentication for Firebase is currently only available on the Google Cloud Identity platform, which is a paid upgrade from Firebase Authentication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048936/what-does-multifactor-mean-in-firebase-auth/63059519#63059519

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: THE BELOW ANSWER IS FOR EMAIL VERIFICATION. NOT 2FA.
The option is available. You simply check if email is verified from your code.

For flutter, this is how you do it:

```
User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

if (user!= null && user.emailVerified) {
  // allow access.
}
```

1. Flutter [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I think you are referring to the verification of an email. On the other hand 2FA is for the **login** process itself

Comment: Sorry about that. Please check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886244/firebase-authentication-with-multi-factor-authentication

Comment: I didn't focus enough on Flutter/Android topics on my search :-( Thanks a lot!!